# Aggregating multiple values of single key into a single bucket elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have a elastic search index with following mapping

```
 {
  "probe_alert" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "alert" : {
        "properties" : {
          "id" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "probeChannelId" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "severity" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sample indexed data : For each channel index has a severity value

```
[
      {
        "_index" : "probe_alert",
        "_type" : "alert",
        "_id" : "b_cu0nYB8EMvknGcmMxk",
        "_score" : 0.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "b_cu0nYB8EMvknGcmMxk",
          "probeChannelId" : 15,
          "severity" : 2,
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "probe_alert",
        "_type" : "alert",
        "_id" : "b_cu0nYB8EMvknGcmMxk",
        "_score" : 0.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "b_cu0nYB8EMvknGcmMxk",
          "probeChannelId" : 17,
          "severity" : 5,
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "probe_alert",
        "_type" : "alert",
        "_id" : "b_cu0nYB8EMvknGcmMxk",
        "_score" : 0.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "b_cu0nYB8EMvknGcmMxk",
          "probeChannelId" : 18,
          "severity" : 10,
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "probe_alert",
        "_type" : "alert",
        "_id" : "b_cu0nYB8EMvknGcmMxk",
        "_score" : 0.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "b_cu0nYB8EMvknGcmMxk",
          "probeChannelId" : 19,
          "severity" : 5,
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "probe_alert",
        "_type" : "alert",
        "_id" : "b_cu0nYB8EMvknGcmMxk",
        "_score" : 0.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "b_cu0nYB8EMvknGcmMxk",
          "probeChannelId" :20,
          "severity" : 10,
        }
      }
    ]
```

I have done terms aggregation for fetching max severity value for a single probeChannelId but now I want to aggregate on multiple values of probeChannelId and get max value of severity.
Expected Result :

```
"aggregations" : {
    "aggs_by_channels" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : [15,17],
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "aggs_by_severity" : {
            "value" : 5.0
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : [18,19,20],
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "aggs_by_severity" : {
            "value" : 10.0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

In response i want group of values probeChannelId to have highest severity value

Comment: can you please share some sample index data and expected search result ?

Comment: @ESCoder i have added the sample data and expected response

Comment: Also i have checked Adjacency matrix aggregation , but that aggregates data across groups and not individual groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get **the highest severity value**, among a set of documents, then you can try out the below query using the [Adjacency matrix aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-adjacency-matrix-aggregation.html)

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "interactions": {
      "adjacency_matrix": {
        "filters": {
          "[15,17]": {
            "terms": {
              "probeChannelId": [
                15,
                17
              ]
            }
          },
          "[18,19,20]": {
            "terms": {
              "probeChannelId": [
                18,
                19,
                20
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_severity": {
          "max": {
            "field": "severity"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "interactions": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "[15,17]",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "max_severity": {
            "value": 5.0           // note this
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "[18,19,20]",
          "doc_count": 3,
          "max_severity": {
            "value": 10.0        // note this
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Thanks man, understood how  Adjacency matrix aggregation will work. @ESCoder